# Representar el valor de una constante simbólica de una interfaz en un diagrama UML

Tags: java, uml

¿Es válido poner el valor de la constante simbólica (`static final`) declarada dentro de una interfaz en el diagrama *UML*?

El motivo de la pregunta es que los atributos de las interfaces deben ser además de `public`, también `static` y `final`.

Comment: Técnicamente, en una interfaz java si se pueden declarar constantes estáticas, ahora no veo por que no ponerlo en el diagrama UML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las variables estáticas se escriben por convención en mayúsculas en el código, y en UML se suele hacer lo mismo para diferenciarlas del resto de las variables de clase. Con esto se evita la necesidad de agregar la cláusula static en UML. Para evitar agregar la clausula final em UML se puede escribir en itálica como convención. Luego el valor de la constante, si agrega informacion util, se puede agregar tranquilamente en UML.